# How to read iptables -L output?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm rather new to iptables, and I'm trying to understand its output. I tried to RTFM, but to no avail when it comes to little details like these. When `iptables -vnL` gives me a line such as:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 2199 packets, 304K bytes)
```

I understand the first part: on incoming data, if the list below this line does not provide any exceptions, then the default policy is to DROP incoming packets. But what does the `2199 packets, 304K bytes` part mean? Is that all the packets that were dropped? Is there any way to find out which packets that were, and where they came from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's showing how many packets and how many bytes were subject to the default rule. If you want more details, add a `-j LOG` rule to the end of the INPUT chain.